# LibreOffice Writer inserts picture only on first page

Tags: libreoffice

All examples show inserting a picture on first page of document (when not just in an empty document).

I have tried unsuccessfully to anchor an inserted image to a particular paragraph or character, but LOW will only put it on and allow me to move it around on the very first page.

I've tried dragging the picture, I've tried dragging the little anchor icon, I've tried looking for solutions by right-clicking the image, etc. Nothing appears to allow me to place the image where it is an appropriate illustration deep in my multipage document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the image's anchor:
[image]

There are various options available - to paragraph/character generally works:

> ### Anchoring images
>
> You can anchor images as a character or to a page, paragraph, or
> character. The method you choose depends on what you are trying to
> achieve.
>
> **To Page** The image keeps the same position in relation to the page margins. It does not move as you add or delete text or other graphics.
> This method is useful when the image does not need to be visually
> associated with a particular piece of text. It is often used when
> producing newsletters or other documents that are very layout
> intensive, or for placing logos in letterheads.
>
> **To Paragraph** The image is associated with a paragraph and moves with the paragraph. It may be placed in the margin or another
> location. This method is useful as an alternative to a table for
> placing icons beside paragraphs.
>
> **To Character** The image is associated with a character but is not in the text sequence. It moves with the paragraph but may be placed in
> the margin or another location. This method is similar to anchoring to
> a paragraph but cannot be used with drawing objects.
>
> **As Character** The image is placed in the document like any other character and, therefore, affects the height of the text line and the
> line break. The graphic moves with the paragraph as you add or delete
> text before the paragraph. This method is useful for keeping images in
> sequence in a procedure (by anchoring them as a character in a blank
> paragraph) or for adding a small (inline) icon in sequence in a
> sentence.
>
> **To Frame** If the image has been placed in a frame, you can anchor the graphic in a fixed position inside the frame. The frame can then
> be anchored to the page, a paragraph, or a character, as required.

<sup>[Source](http://www.taming-openoffice-org.com/newsite/?page_id=14)</sup>

Comment: Pursuing this answer, the operation began to work though it was not precisely by this that it worked. Nevertheless, it does work now. Thanks.